# OpenVAS commands getting Failed Authentication error

Tags: authentication, centos, centos7, openvas

while trying to run some of OpenVAS CLI commands, i'm getting Failed Authentication error message. OpenVAS is installed on CentOS machine. I tried with the user account credentials but still getting the same error message.Is there any way to over come this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok now I tried and found the solution.
For every OpenVAS command we should provide the username and password.

EX:

```
openvas-cli -u xxxx -w xxxxxxx -g

openvas-cli -u xxxx -w xxxxxxx -g
```

Answer (score 0):

failed to authenticate means password policy file is not present in openvas. Hence you need rebuild openvas "openvasmd --rebuild" and create certificate as well "openvas-mkcert"